# Powershell Inputbox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm trying to have an input box to prompt the user to enter the group instead of hard coding it. Thanks in advance.

```
$users = gc "C:\Users\raw.admin\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\users_list.txt"

foreach($u in $users)
{
   Add-ADGroupMember XA-MS_Products -Members $u
}
```

I found this snipit of someone elses code but I'm not sure how to adapt it for what I want.

```
function point ($x,$y)
{
   New-Object Drawing.Point $x,$y
}

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") > $null
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") > $null

$form = New-Object Windows.forms.form
$form.text = "Drive Space Results"
$form.size = point 600 400

$label1 = New-Object Windows.forms.Label
$label1.location = point 225 25
$label1.size = point 300 25
$label1.text = "MASTER DOMAIN ONLY"


$label2 = New-Object Windows.forms.Label
$label2.location = point 25 75
$label2.size = point 120 100
$label2.text = "Enter Server Name:"

$input1 = New-Object Windows.forms.TextBox
$input1.location = point 150 75
$input1.size = point 350 75


$run = New-Object Windows.forms.Button
$run.text="RUN"
$run.Location = point 150 120
$run.size = point 100 50
$run.add_click({
   runCall($input1.text)
})

$exit = New-Object Windows.forms.Button
$exit.text="EXIT"
$exit.Location = point 300 120
$exit.size = point 100 50
$exit.add_click({
   $form.close()
})

$out = New-Object Windows.forms.TextBox
$out.location = point 25 200
 $out.size = point 525 150
$out.Anchor = "bottom"
$out.Multiline = $true

$form.controls.addrange(($label1,$label2,$input1,$run,$exit,$out))
$form.add_shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: here's a [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff730941.aspx) that shows you the basics of how to use a winform from powershell. Your code above looks similar: I think all you need to so is change `$form.ShowDialog()` to `[void] $form.ShowDialog()` and add a new line like `$x` to save the user's input into a variable (`$x` in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you avoid using a custom form, it requires a lot of code, just use a default `InputBox`. Here is a fast example

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic;
$value = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter group name', 'XA Group', '')
```

In `$value` you will find text user entered

Comment: This does what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how to user the sample code I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Ie.

```
    $users = gc "C:\Users\raw.admin\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\users_list.txt"
    $group = Read-Host "Enter Group To Display"

    foreach($u in $users)
    {
       Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $u
    }
```

Comment: That is one option but I would really like to know how to present the user with a popup box. There is no reason why your answer wont work. I am fairly new to Powershell and would like to add a little something to the scripts I create.